# How to send SMS from Chat flow in Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio, twilio-flex

I have a studio flow that receives chat messages (from Whatsapp) and forward the conversation to Flex.
I'm trying to send a SMS notification to a hard-coded number as this happen.

The issue is that the SMS is never sent and the Send Message widget fails with the following log:
`Failure sending message: Chat service or channel parameter missing`

I understand that it's probably because the flow has a Chat context and that the widget expects a Chat Service. But I want to send a SMS.

I tried to configure the Send Message widget like this:

- `SEND MESSAGE FROM` and `SEND MESSAGE TO` set and all other config fields empty
- `SEND MESSAGE FROM` and `SEND MESSAGE TO` and `PROGRAMMABLE CHAT SERVICE` with a Messaging Service ID (which doesn't really make sense but hey...)

Neither worked.

How can I send a SMS from a Chat flow in Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I was just able to knock up a quick Studio Flow that receives messages from WhatsApp and sends out an SMS to a hard-coded number and it worked for me. The way I did it was to hard code both the *Send message from* and *Send message to* numbers in the *Messaging & chat config* section of the *Send Message* widget, like this:

[image]

In this case you must ensure that the *Send message from* number is a Twilio number that is able to send SMS messages.

Comment: It's weird, I did exactly that and it never worked. I spent half my day trying different numbers belonging/not belonging to messaging services... I ended up triggering a second flow which sends the SMS. But I had to trigger it via a REST call because calling it as a subflow would have the exact same behavior.
Did you set this up in a Flex subaccount too ?

Comment: I did not set this up in a Flex project, maybe that would change things. One other suggestion, rather than trigger another Studio flow you could trigger a Twilio Function and use it to send the message. I’ll try this in a Flex project and see what I find.